# Transform pandas dataframe into a different structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with this structure:

| ID | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |

I would like to transform it into a dataframe like this:

| ID | Activity_A | Activity_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |

So making the ID column unique, and creating a separate column for each Activity, and counting the number of activities for each ID.

Thank you for your help.

I'm not sure how to start. I understand there is a get_dummies() function, but is it applicable here?

Comment: use a `crosstab`